# How would I hypothetically give submittable text an integer value in one js file and visualize it on an analytics page on another js file?

Tags: javascript, database, analytics, file-transfer, data-transfer

I've been having trouble for days trying to figure this out. I am able to transfer some basic methods like `alert()` and `console.log()` using `function include(file)` and I am able to display plain integers assigned to variables on a **bar graph in a browser, but I can't seem to do anything more complex. I tried assigning integers along with strings to a *variable, but the bar graph don't show up. Can anybody give me any pointers on how I could do this?

What I am trying to do is display on a graph how many bugs users have reported through bug tracking webpage.

*An example of what I tried:

```
var issue = {
        id: issueId,
        description: issueDesc,
        severity: issueSeverity,
        assignedTo: issueAssignedTo,
        status: issueStatus
    } && +1
```

**The code I used for the bar graph

```
var intVal = 5
var numArr = function(){
    return Array.from({length: 2}, () => intVal);
}
```